# cookielib: How to save Python cookies and load it?

Tags: python, linux, command-line, cookies

I am using CentOS 5.5 and Python.

The following code works perfectly,

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : 'myname', 'password' : '123456'})
resp = opener.open('http://www.example.com/signin.html', login_data)
```

However, I want to save the cookies to `/var/www/html/cookies` and load it when I need, so I don't have to sign in every time, just like the browsers do.

How can I save and load the cookies? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cookielib` defines a separate [FileCookieJar](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.FileCookieJar) class that has the functionality you're looking for.